# How do I sharpen photos on my phone?

Tags: photos

I am looking for a photo editor app or website that will let me sharpen photos, preferably using unsharp mask.

I tried several free photo editors from the market, but none of them lets me sharpen photos. I don't mind paying for an app, I just don't want to unless I know it is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [PicSay](http://www.appbrain.com/app/picsay-pro-photo-editor/com.shinycore.picsaypro)'s free version and been happy with it.  I'll probably upgrade to the full version which has the ability to sharpen, but just haven't really had the need yet so I've been putting it off.  I'll report back if I do chip down.

Another alternative would be to use Pixlr's web based editor: http://pixlr.com/editor

Provided you have flash installed you can use their browser based editor that does have an "Unsharp Mask" filter.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using Camera 360. It's a great all in one app and it makes most photos extremely clear. Try it. It has a free trial so you can try it before. :)

Answer (score -1):

I like using [Adobe Photoshop Express](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.psmobile) because it makes photos look sharper and a whole list of other things too. I'm no photographer, and this app makes my pictures look professional.